# Почему, если присвоить первому массиву второй массив, то все манипуляции со вторым массивом также присваиваются первому массиву?

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

С тем, как этого избежать я уже разобрался, нужно просто присвоить элементы второго массива элементам первого:

```
int[] noSortNum = new int[32];

        for (int i =0;i<noSortNum.length;i++){
            noSortNum[i]=num[i];
        }
```

Однако до сих пор не могу понять, что происходило до этого, я присваивал:

```
int[] noSortNum = num;
```

Сортировал массив `num`, после чего массив `noSortNum` также становился отсортированным.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это работает и для чего это было сделанно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас есть объект массива в памяти и ссылка на него num.
Когда вы вызвали `int[] noSortNum = num;` вы создали вторую ссылку на тот же самый объект в памяти. Естественно когда вы его отсортировали - вы по обоим ссылкам увидели один и тот же отсортированный массив